# A SimpleStackDemo, and using loops to return values from an array, LIFO

Tags: java, arrays, stack

This is a programming assignment from a class I am in.  I do not want you to solve it for me, just help me understand.  I will say as well, the professor is very rigid about how the program should look, so please don't give me a solution which changes any of the names(unless they should be reserved.)  Also, we have not covered stacks, pop() or push(), so I looked ahead 4 chapters to even get an inkling of what he is looking for.

This is the code he has given us.

```
    public class SimpleStack {

        char[] data;//this array holds that stack
        int tos;    //index of top of stack

        //Construct an empty stack given it's size.
        public SimpleStack(int size){
            data = new char[size];

            tos = 0;
        }

        public void push(char ch){
            if(isFull()){
                System.out.println("--Stack is full.");
                return;
            }
            data[tos] = ch;
            tos++;
        }

        public char pop(){
            if(isEmpty()){
                System.out.println("--Stack is empty.");
                return (char)0;
            }
            tos--;
            return data[tos];
        }

        public isEmpty(){
            boolean empty(tos = 0);
        }

        public isFull(){

        }
}
```

I am supposed to finish the two boolean statements at the bottom, which I have an idea of how I do that.  Also I am supposed to create the main method to call the SimpleStack, and input A-J as a ten character test, then have it give me the reverse.  I am not told how I should construct the main, but the prof also does not say I need to get user input.  So I could just create an array already filled from A-J.

I tested my main using this code.  I could ask for the user to give me the starting letter "A" and then create a loop to end it before "K", and I was also testing how I might send to SimpleStack the size the array is supposed to be.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class SimpleStackDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        char c[] = "ABCDEFGHIJ".toCharArray();
        int aryL = c.length;

        SimpleStack sS1 = new SimpleStack(aryL);

        //System.out.println("The Array is, " + aryL); 


        //SimpleStack sS1 = new SimpleStack(//something);

    }

}
```

What I think I want to do is ask the user for how big the array should be, use that to call on SimpleStack, then ask what letter they want to start at, which will then be put to tos?

Comment: Are you sure you mean FIFO? Stacks are generally LIFO. Think about what a stack of books is. You add books to the top of the stack, and remove from the top.

Comment: Yes yes, my brain is scrambled right now...  LIFO

Comment: Queue is FIFO. Not related to the question:  if you can add another instance variable for `size` you can implement `isFull()`, `return tos == size -1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, `isFull` is easy to do. Why? When instantiating your `SimpleStack`, the user must specify the size of the stack, and that size is used to create `data`. You know what index you're on, `tos`. All you have to do is check if the `tos` is the last index:

```
 return (tos == data.length - 1);
```

`isEmpty` follows the same idea. `tos` is your current index. All you have to do is check if your current index is 0:

```
 return (tos == 0);
```

Things to note:

When you `push()` or `pop()`, your `tos` increases or decreases, keeping track of your index. Because you know where you are in the stack, you can always tell relative to the absolutes whether you're at the either end of the Stack.

In your main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    char c[] = "ABCDEFGHIJ".toCharArray();
    int aryL = c.length;

    SimpleStack sS1 = new SimpleStack(aryL); // You have a stack with size 10;
    System.out.println(sS1.isEmpty()); // on index 0, will return true.
    sS1.push('A'); // Adds A to top of empty stack, tos = 1 after this line
    sS1.push('B'); // Adds B to top of empty stack, tos = 2 after this line
    sS1.push('C'); // Adds C to top of empty stack, tos = 3 after this line
    sS1.pop();     // Removes top of empty stack, tos = 2 after this line
    sS1.push('C'); // Adds C to top of empty stack, tos = 3 after this line

    // Stack now looks like:
    //  C 
    //  B
    //  A -> bottom of stack

}
```

Comment: So, I will have to get some input from the user to initiate the size of the array.  And tos is where ever the stack is, which builds upwards.  So empty, it returns 0, but put in 3 letters, and now it is on C.

so, inside the stack it looks like this:

    `C`
    `B`
    `A` , with C sitting on top.

Comment: You already do this by: `SimpleStack sS1 = new SimpleStack(aryL);`

Comment: Hmmmm, ok.  I thought this is what the method was doing.  Ok.  I think I can see where I will go with this now.

Comment: You gave me some good clues and I was able to construct my answer.